# Update Gridview - from 2 different source

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview connected to SQL DB via a Objectdatasorce.

I first insert a record with data collected from textboxes.

On update, user enters 2 fields on the gridview - MarketValue & PercentAllocated. 
These 2 values effect a field OperatingCost, which needs at least 10 other textbox inputs to calculate.

Is there a way I can intercept the Gridview Update Command & grab the 2 values the user entered (MarketValue & PercentAllocated) & calculate the OperatingCost & update the 3 values (MarketValue & PercentAllocated & OperatingCost) at one shot?

Answer (score 0):

Please try Objectdatasource's onupdating event. for more info

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.updating.aspx